# how to perform a bitwise operator on result in postegres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have several rows, and I would like to perform a bitwise OR on the result, how can I do this in Postgres 9.x ?

e.g.
my table contains

```
Name col1 col2
--------------
John    1    2
Walter  1    1
Ron     1    2
```

I know would like to perform select statements so that I get OR of all (or a subset of) values from a column.

E.g.

```
select [magical statement OR col1] from table
would give me
1

select [magical statement OR col2] from table
would give me
3
```

I hope you can understand what I mean, I cant figure out what the proper term is for what I want.

Comment: "9.x" isn't much use as a PostgreSQL version, by the way. PostgreSQL's weird versioning means that major versions are 9.0, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, etc. Each is significantly different. See http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/ . Best to post the full version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select bit_or(col1) from table group by col1;
```

Reference (it may not be present in your version, so check the documentation):

[Aggregate functions - PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-aggregate.html).