# BitWise OR on a Binary Data Type column in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table like below in my Postgres 9.4 DB

```
id(integer), data (bytea, Binary Data Type)
1, B'1000'
2, B'1001'
3, B'1100'
...
```

and I want to take bitwise OR off the data column in a single query like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40937716/is-there-a-way-to-do-bitwise-or-on-any-column-using-single-query)

Is there any efficient way to do this in Postgres?

Thanks in Anticipation!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to perform a bitwise operator on result in postegres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13183880/how-to-perform-a-bitwise-operator-on-result-in-postegres)

Comment: @underscore_d thanks for the above link but i was looking for a binary data type column OR aggregation. link which you have mentioned uses bit_or() function which doesn't supports Binary Data Type.

Comment: Why don't you use the `bit` data type for that? The `bytea` sounds like the wrong type.

Comment: `B'1001'` **is not** a valid `bytea` literal, it's a representation of the type `bit(4)`.